# Commit tran en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dudas que este correcto mi SP ya que no sé si se deba utilizar solo una vez `begin try` y esas instrucciones, aparte regresa un 1 pero no hace el `update`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EliminarVariableFormula]
    @IdVariableElimina int, @ValorElimina varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE  @Activo bit = 0    


    if @ValorElimina <> '' 
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN  
            UPDATE ValoresDeVariables SET Activo=@Activo WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina AND ValorDeVariable=@ValorElimina
        COMMIT TRAN
        SELECT 1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        SELECT 0, 'Hubo un error.'
    END CATCH
    else
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN  
            UPDATE ValoresDeVariables SET Activo=@Activo WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina
        COMMIT TRAN
        SELECT 1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        SELECT 0, 'Hubo un error.'
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando lo ejecutas?

Comment: @Alfabravo unicamente regresa un 1 pero no hace el update

Comment: Si la consistencia de la operación depende que los dos `update` se ejecuten perfectamente, la transacción involucrará a ambos. Sino, no tiene sentido abrir un transacción por sentencia.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tiene algo que ver que tenga en un if los dos updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplificando un poco, tu procedimiento es algo así:

```
Si <condicion>
   udpate 1
sino
   update 2
```

Por consiguiente tus `updates` son excluyentes, o se ejecuta uno o se ejecuta el otro. Nunca ambos. Ahora bien, **¿Por qué necesitaríamos usar una transacción en este caso?**

El uso habitual de una transacción es brindar consistencia en una operación que involucra minímamente al menos dos sentencias, supongamos que tuvieras que  actualizar `ValoresDeVariables` pero antes, insertar un registro en una segunda tabla, por ejemplo `ValoresDeVariablesLog` para registrar el valor anterior a la actualización, de nuevo, es solo un ejemplo.

```
INSERT INTO ValoresDeVariablesLog (IDVariable, Activo, Fecha)
       SELECT IDVariable, Activo, GETDATE()
              FROM ValoresDeVariables
              WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina

UPDATE ValoresDeVariables 
       SET Activo=@Activo 
       WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina
```

En este caso, imaginemos que lo que necesitamos que las dos operaciones sean atómicas, es decir que funcionen ambas o ninguna para que la operación sea consistente. Sin una transacción, lo que podría ocurrir eventualmente, que el primer `insert` funcione y el `update` final no. Eso es justamente lo que no queríamos en un principio y para eso están las transacciones, si alguna sentencia falla, ejecutaremos un `ROLLBACK` si por el contrario todo funciona, haremos un `COMMIT`, hay varias formas de construir una sentencia transaccionada, está es una de ellas, usando el `TRY/CATCH`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION MiTransaccion
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO ValoresDeVariablesLog (IDVariable, Activo, Fecha)
           SELECT IDVariable, Activo, GETDATE()
                  FROM ValoresDeVariables
                  WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina

    UPDATE ValoresDeVariables 
           SET Activo=@Activo 
           WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina

    COMMIT TRANSACTION MiTransaccion
END 
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MiTransaccion
END
```

Un aclaración, una transacción normalmente se deshace frente a un error de base de datos, que es lo que estamos haciendo con el `TRY/CATCH` sin embargo también podría deshacerse por una lógica de negocio, pero esto obviamente se controla de otra forma ya que no tienes un error sino un estado/condición que eventualmente debes verificar.

Ahora volvamos a la pregunta original: ¿Por qué necesitaríamos usar una transacción en este caso?. La respuesta: **en este caso no tiene sentido**. ¿Por qué? bien ya hemos visto que hay dos sentencias `update` excluyentes, y el otro datos importante, es que toda sentencia de `update/insert/delete` es atómica, es decir, se ejecuta completamente o no lo hace. Nunca podría darse el caso que alguna de esta operaciones se ejecute a medias. Implícitamente cuando haces:

```
UPDATE ValoresDeVariables SET Activo=@Activo WHERE IDVariable=@IdVariableElimina AND ValorDeVariable=@ValorElimina
```

o la otra sentencia, el motor maneja la misma como si fuera una transacción, por lo que indicarlo explícitamente, es redundante.

**Aclaración**: No lo detalle para no extenderme, pero una transacción también puede llegar a manejar la atomicidad de los datos que se leen, pero tampoco pareciera ser el caso en este ejemplo.

Comment: @Ivxn estoy totalmente de acuerdo con la respuesta de Patricio. Además considero que existe otro punto a tomar en cuentra y que es independiente de las transacicones, me refiero a que (tomando en cuenta el código del OP) el `UPDATE` se puede ejecutar pero dadas las condiciones puede que no se afecte ningún registro, y en lugar de hacer un `SELECT 1` se puede poner un `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` por lo menos para saber cuántos registros fueron afectados. Otra opción es hacer un debug o aún mejor, usar el Profiler para saber exactamente qué operaciones se realizan en el manejador de BD